# IIS URL rewrite with special characters

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I am trying to write a rewrite rule in IIS 8.5 that throws 404 error when a string is found in the URL.

My current rule

```
        <rule name="BlockscheduledJobs-Rule2" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*scheduledJobs*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Error" statusDescription="Error" />
        </rule>
```

This rule works fine when the URL format is like

```
https://www.example.com/scheduledJobs/test.aspx
```

but doesn't work when it is like

```
https://www.example.com/index.aspx?task=scheduledJobs.test.run.aspx&value=job&result=true
```

how can i get my rule working for below URL format

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the rule as mentioned below fixed my issue.

```
<rule name="BlockscheduledJobs-Rule2" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*scheduledJobs.*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Error" statusDescription="Error" />
        </rule>
```